# Как настроить nginx на перенаправление по адресу и порту в зависимости от поддомена?

Tags: nginx, dns, поддомены

Что нужно.
Есть 2 поддомена

- site1.localhost;
- site2.localhost;

Если переходить по адресу

> site1.localhost должен перенаправлять на localhost:4001
>
> site2.localhost должен перенаправлять на localhost:4002

Настройка конфига nginx. Но не работает.
Сам nginx должен слушать 80 порт?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site1.localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4001;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site2.localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4002;
    }
}
```

Comment: Должно работать. Nginx перезапущен? Что показывает `nginx -t` ?

Comment: И что именно значит «не работает»?

Comment: Ошибка 502 Bad Gateway если в барузере перейти на site1.localhost.

Команда nginx -t показывает 
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Конфиг файла nginx внутри контейнера  именно такой как указан, то есть обновлен.

Comment: А приложение-то там работает на `4001` порту? Ошибка говорит что `locahost:4001` никто не слушает.

Comment: Ну да, если перейти в браузере по адресу localhost:4001 то отображается wordpress который запущен в той же сети docker-compose app-network

Comment: Так, стоп. Откуда тут появились докеры? Nginx запущен в отдельном докер-контейнере?

Comment: Нет, как docker-compose сервис вместе с db и wordpress. Сеть app-network драйвер bridge.

Comment: Ну тогда и проксировать надо не в `localhost`, а в `wordpress`

Comment: Это где proxy_pass?

Comment: да. Каждый контейнер это отдельный «компьютер» и в контейнере с nginx на порту 4001 ничего нет.

Comment: Сейчас попробовал прописал wordpress, сайт отобразился, но без css и стилей. В консоли ошибки, что 

wordpress/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=6.1.1:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: Кажется `proxy_set_header Host site1.localhost;` может помочь

Comment: @AlexeyTen
Да, отлично, спасибо!